# SQL Server : skip a step

Tags: sql-server

Let me expain what I need to do: I have a SQL Server and I sometimes run jobs manually using

```
EXECUTE [msv].[dsf]._sp_startjob 'Test1'
```

This command will start the job Test1 for me.

Job Test1 has 10 steps, sometimes the jobs fails on step 3. My question is how do I skip the step and run it again, but from step 4 to 10? Because if I start it again from step 0, it will fail again at step 3.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Use `@step_name` parameter in `sp_start_job`

```
sp_start_job   
     {   [@job_name =] 'job_name'  
       | [@job_id =] job_id }  
     [ , [@error_flag =] error_flag]  
     [ , [@server_name =] 'server_name']  
     [ , [@step_name =] 'step_name']  
     [ , [@output_flag =] output_flag]
```

> [ @step_name= ] 'step_name' The name of the step at which to begin
>   execution of the job. Applies only to local jobs. step_name is
>   sysname, with a default of NULL

As per your comment,

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'job_name',@step_name = 'test2'
```

Comment: Please be more specific so lets say step one called "test" step 2 called "test1" and step 3 called "test2"  lets say I wanaa skip step 2 do I do EXECUTE [msv].[dsf]._sp_startjob 'jobs's name' "test2" ?

Comment: use parameter name when executing.  `EXECUTE sp_startjob @job_name = 'job_name',@step_name = 'test2'`